# Classic forms control cannot resize in WPF environment

Tags: c#, wpf

I've added a regular forms control but I cannot resize it. Instead I have to resize host.

[MSDN sample: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
    new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
MaskedTextBox mtbDate = new MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");
host.Child = mtbDate;
this.grid1.Children.Add(host);

mtbDate.Width = 200; //Not work!
host.Width = 200; //Workaraound...
```

How can I resize the control, not the host?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, this is how WPF works, once you change the size of the window you should be able to change the size of the Textbox.

Comment: Textbox size is ignored then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page gives a lot of information about hosting WinForms controls in WPF:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952.aspx

The short story is that you are not supposed to resize the textbox- that will be ignored/overridden.  Instead, resize the WindowsFormsHost (either in WPF or via WPF dynamic layout)